# Delombok a java file per feature

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I want to delombok a java file. Per feature I mean that I want to delombok a `val` usage at first. It means to convert parts of code like `val x = "some string";` to pure java code `String x = "some string";`. Also, the other Lombok features can be converted to plain java code. The Lombok project includes this functionality, you can find more details [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok).

In current project we decided to stop using it for various reasons. For example I am well to generate getters and setters using IDE. Also, as for me, `val` usage makes code less readable. I tried one time to delombok the project using IDE plugin, but it makes the code unreadable and awful. Probably there is a way where I can delombok by small steps - for a chosen file and for a chosen Lombok feature.

How can I do this in terminal or in IntelliJ IDEA?
Probably there is no out of the box solution, but you can point me direction where I should look at.

Comment: could you clarify what "delombok" means to you?

Comment: @jhamon If you were familiar with lombok you would know that it ships with a tool called delombok which converts source code with lombok annotations to the equivalent pure java code. I don't think it needs explaining when you get a detailed description from the first result on google.

Comment: I'm rather sure, it's impossible with standard delombok, but maybe the IDEA plugin can more. What do you need it for?

Comment: @Michael, sorry for being familiar with lombok but not having used the related tools. Now I'm gonna have to whip myself for not knowing all and for using a non-english google version that points me to "détroit **de Lombok**" wiki page instead.

Comment: @jhamon as @Michael explained, it means to convert part of codes like `val x = "some string";` to pure java code `String x = "some string";` etc.

@maaartinus In current project we decided to stop using it for various reasons. For example I am well to generate getters and setters using Idea. Also, as for me, `val` usage makes code less readable. I tried one time to delombok the project using Idea plugin, but it makes the code unreadable and awful. Probably there is a way where I can delombok by small steps - for a chosen file and for a chosen lombok feature.

Comment: **There's nothing unclear with this question. Everybody knowing Google can find out what "delombok" means. The meaning of "per feature" is clear as well, given that Lombok 's features are annotations it processes.** That said, the OP could add a link and a sentence to make it even clearer, but IMHO it's already pretty clear.

Comment: You could try to the annotations you want to keep by others, delombok and then replace back. I don't think you can delombok per file, but you can delombok everything to a different directory and replace a single source file only. When done, you can use `flagUsage` in your `lombok.config` to forbid some annotations. `+++` Note that you can use only one username per comment, the others won't get notified.

Comment: @maaartinus Thanks for the suggestions. "Delombok everything and replace a single a single source file only" - I agree this can be done without doing complex work, but it still engages too much manual work. I want to start with simply replacing `val` usage. It is very simple manual work, not consuming too much time, but I want to eliminate it to 0 time, to not require manual work at all. I don't want to replace one simple work with another one.

Comment: "delombok by file" - you can automate it easily with a simple script. Or maybe using meld (or alike), comparing the original and delomboked source trees. `+++` The important part is "delombok by feature". My above comment is mangled, repeated: Try something like: 1. `perl -pe -i 's/import lombok\.(Getter|Setter|....)/import nothing.$1/' 2. delombok, 3. copy over the sources, 4. undo the first step. The compiler may force you to create the "nothing" package with all lombok annotations in order for delombok to work. Your nothing-annotations will be kept as are and you can automate it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lombok plugin in IntelliJ which does the delombok automatically IntelliJ > Refactor > Delombok. 
The plugin can be found at :

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok

Also, project Lombok supports the command line operations, refer the guide :

- https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: after having performed a 'Delombok', any idea how you reverse it?